# Как в программе Tkinter умножать полученные данные от пользователя на числа с плавающей точкой?

Tags: python, tkinter

При любой попытке в программе Tkinter умножить полученные числа от пользователя на заданные числа с плавающей точкой выдает ошибку.
При обозначении примера типа float(TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'), а если int - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0'.

```
num1 = float(a.get())
num2 = float(b.get())
num2 = b.set(num1*785.9)
num1 = a.set(num2*456.7)
```

Нужно чтобы значение первого поля при вводе числа во второе перемножались по примеру и наоборот.

Comment: Если предположить, что в полях ассоциированных с переменными a и b введены корректные числа, то в вышеприведённом куске кода ошибок нет.

Comment: Я тоже никак понять не могу в чем проблема.

Comment: Всё. Дошло. Тоже был невнимательным.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите присваивание когда делаете `.set(...)`.

```
b.set(num1*785.9)
a.set(num2*456.7)
```

Эти функции ничего не возвращают (т.е. по сути возвращают `None`). И этим вы перетираете значения в переменных `num1` и `num2`.